# String replacement

Tags: php, regex, string

For example i have this string:

`$test_str = "num Test \n num Hello \n num World";`

And i need to replace these `num`-s to increasing numbers. like that

`"1 Test \n 2 Hello \n 3 World"`

How could i do this?

Comment: May I ask you to describe here a real case, not oversimplified one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use preg_replace_callback

```
$test_str = "num Test \n num Hello \n num World";

function replace_inc( $matches ) {
    static $counter = 0; // start value
    return $counter++;
}

$output = preg_replace_callback( '/num/', 'replace_inc', $test_str );
```

Cheers,
haggi

Comment: Your example would return the numbers off by 1, right? (0,1,2) To answer correctly, you should modify your function to return ++$counter or start with $counter=1

Comment: i thought adjusting "// start value" should be easy enough ;)

of course, you could also use the prefix-increment which is btw. generally faster, but this could have been a little confusing to somebody who is not that much into programming

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by `substr_count`. ([php doc](http://nl.php.net/substr_count)

Then loop through your string and, use a counter for the recplace. And put something like `echo str_replace("num", $count, $str)`.

Comment: Well, i can count `num`-s by substr_count as well. But str_replace will replace all `num`-s in `$str`, so what the point? Or i just don't understand smth?

Answer (score 0):

This version works for any number of "num"

```
<?php
  $num = 2;
  $s = "a num b num c num";

  while(strpos($s, "num") !== false) $s = preg_replace("/num/",$num++,$s,1);

  echo "$s\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Variant #1**: PHP 5.3+ (anonymous functions)

```
$count=0;
echo preg_replace_callback('/\bnum\b/',
                           function($v){global $count; return ++$count;},
                           $test_str) ;
```

**Variant #2**: regex substitiution eval

```
$count=0;
echo preg_replace('/\bnum\b/e', '++$count', $test_str);
```

Regards

rbo